# What is process flow for booking hotel in sabre using SOAP API

Tags: soap, nusoap, sabre

I am using SOAP SABRE API for booking hotel. I want to know what is the process flow for the same for creating fresh PNR as well as booking hotel in existing PNR containing AIR Iterinrary.

Answer (score 1):

**The typical workflow is:**
1. OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ - displays hotel availability.
2. HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ - displays a hotel property description.
3. HotelRateDescriptionLLSRQ - displays a hotel rate description.
4. OTA_HotelResLLSRQ - books a hotel room.

You can find these services here:
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/hotel

Since the hotel booking process and information is very related to native Sabre, I also recommend you to check Format Finder, for general information (you should be able to login with the same credentials you use for creating sessions):
https://formatfinder.sabre.com/Content/Hotels.aspx?ItemID=D29735017BA346888DCE18CB52D69AA6

For adding PNR related information, you can always use PassengerDetails service, most of the required fields are there. Specially for selling hotels, try having the agency address and the traveler name added before selling, if not the sell request could fail.

Answer (score 0):

> **AS PER SABRE DEV STUDIO I AM PROVIDING THE WORKFLOW OF HOTEL :**
>
> Go to this url for reference:
>
> https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/workflows/Book_Hotel_Reservation
>
> **Book Hotel Reservation The following workflow allows you to search and
>   book a hotel room.**
>
> **Steps** 
>   **Step 1:** Retrieve hotel availability using OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ.
>
> **Step 2:** Retrieve hotel rates using HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ.
>
> **Step 3:** Retrieve hotel rules and policies using
>   HotelRateDescriptionLLSRQ.*
>
> **Step 4:** Add any additional (required) information to create the
>   passenger name record (PNR) using PassengerDetailsRQ.**
>
> **Step 5:** Book a room for the selected hotel using OTA_HotelResLLSRQ.
>
> **Step 6:** End the transaction of the passenger name record using
>   EndTransactionLLSRQ.
>
> **Note
>   * Mandatory only if selected option in response of HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ contains HRD_RequiredForSell="true".
>
> ** Ensure Agency address is added within call to PassengerDetails, so as the OTA_HotelResLLSRQ call is not rejected.**